# Flutter Firebase Auth / Google_sign_in fail to login with statuscode=CANCELED

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-signin

This is my pubspec.yaml. I'm using Flutter:

```
dependencies:
flutter:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
shared_preferences: ^0.4.2
json_serializable: ^1.2.1
camera: ^0.2.3
path_provider: ^0.4.1
simple_permissions: ^0.1.6
share: ^0.5.3
#Google Sign_In
firebase_auth: ^0.5.20
google_sign_in: ^3.0.5
```

I cannot authenticate with the Google Sign In method. The window shows up normally and after my app throws a error:

```
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, Status{statusCode=CANCELED, resolution=null}, null)
```

Haven't found any solutions online, can someone help me out?

The following is my `_signIn()` method

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn() async {

GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
GoogleSignInAuthentication gSA = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

FirebaseUser user = await auth.signInWithGoogle(
    idToken: gSA.idToken, accessToken: gSA.accessToken);

print("User Name : ${user.displayName}");
return user;
}
```

My code crashes after I call `GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();` so my guess was, that my setup was wrong.

This is how I call the `_signIn()`

```
MaterialButton(
        child: Text("Google Sign-In"),
        onPressed: (){
          _signIn()
            .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
            .catchError((e) => print(e));
        },
      ),
```

I already deleted the Firebase-Project on the google dev console online and created a new one. Also I tried the anonymous login -> worked fine

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to fix this problem with using a APK in **release** mode!

What you have to do:

Build your app in release mode and add the SHA1 or SHA256 to your firebase project.

If you don't know how to [prepare your app for release](https://flutter.io/android-release/) you can do this quickly.

Comment: If you resolve the problem that way.. it looks like, at least, Gainz's answer was helpful for you to solve the problem. You might solve that problem without being release mode, if you see the description carefully. You might be able to add the SHA thing even you are on the dev mode. Just my personal feel is that you should select Gainz's answer as the answer and add your explain as a comment not the answer.

Comment: @Vincent no, because his solution was not successfull for me.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into the same issue.
This is how I solved it.

1) Get your SHA1 certificate key. (see https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

2) Place the SHA1 key in your Firebase console

3) Rebuild your flutter App and try again. It should be working now.

Comment: Are you sure you ran into the same issue? My statusCode is CANCELED!

It did not work for me.