# Flutter: Can't update the firebase_auth package from 0.5.11 to 0.6.6

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm trying to update the package in order to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446960/flutter-firebase-auth-google-sign-in-fail-to-login-with-statuscode-canceled). When I change the firebase_auth version on my pubspec.yaml I obtain this:

**error**

```
Configure project :firebase_auth

Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth'.
> Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for 1hd54il9uhc3eutyaybhw2pq0
(~/.gradle/caches/4.10.2/scripts-remapped/build_7iuv4c9gs2g2ad3uvhc3eae18/1hd54il9uhc3eutyaybhw2pq0/cp_proj70b1361a260e0ceb212a59c45f680ebd).
> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
Command: ~/git-repo/mine-repo/printer_products/android/gradlew app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

**pubspec**

```
dependencies:
   flutter:
      sdk: flutter

   #firebase_auth: ^0.5.11
   firebase_auth: ^0.6.6
   google_sign_in: ^3.0.4
   firebase_core: ^0.2.5+1
   cloud_firestore: ^0.7.3

   firebase_storage: ^1.0.4
   image_picker: ^0.4.10
   http: ^0.12.0
   uuid: ^1.0.3
   mime: ^0.9.6+2
   shared_preferences: "^0.4.3"
   rxdart: "^0.19.0"
   scoped_model: "^1.0.1"
```

Seems that only the combination of firebase_auth: 0.5.11 and google_sign_in: 3.0.4 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I realized that the problem was not caused directly by the package and its update, I found the solution on this question. I simply removed the cache mentioned on the error: `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/4.10.2`